# How I Programmed the Musik off and on Button?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, audio

I want to develop a little App. But I try to make an Musik off Button since a couple of days. Maybe you could help me.
I start like this.

```
func MusikAN (sender: UIButton!) {
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.setBackgroundImage(MusikEin, forState: .Normal)
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.addTarget(self, action: "MusikAus:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
func MusikAus (sender: UIButton!){
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.setBackgroundImage(MusikAus, forState: .Normal)
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.addTarget(self, action: "MusikAN:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

And I make the Musik with this function.

```
func Musik (sender: UIButton) {

    var alertsound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blub1", ofType: "mp3")!)

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertsound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()

}
```

But it does not work. The sound is coming. 
When you push the "MusikAus" Button, you have to hear no Music and when you push the "MusikAn" Button, you have to hear music again.

Comment: is the MusikAus function getting called when you press the off button?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to call addTarget each time you press the button (it's ADD, not SET). Like that from the second click on, you'll call BOTH methods, probably even multiple times, at once. So either call removeTarget before adding a new one or better set and use the selected state of the button to switch between the two methods.
Also, the MusikAN method does not even call something on the audio player, so how should it continue playing then after you stopped it?

Answer (score 0):

I update the code maybe it is now right.

```
func MusikAN (sender: UIButton!) {
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.setBackgroundImage(MusikEin, forState: .Normal)
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.removeTarget(self, action: "MusikAn:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.addTarget(self, action: "MusikAus:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    audioPlayer.start()
}
func MusikAus (sender: UIButton!){
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.setBackgroundImage(MusikAus, forState: .Normal)
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.removeTarget(self, action: "MusikAus:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    MusikEinUndAusSchalten.addTarget(self, action: "MusikAN:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```